# How can I create an .EXE file from .NET Framework 4.8 project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

As the question states, How can I create an .EXE file from .NET Framework 4.8 project? This is a Windows Forms Application.

When I publish my application, I get the following files/directory created:

[image]

I can run the setup.exe file to download the application, and from there can open the application from my system or through the TapeRedGreen.application file.

Many other users have had an issue in their project properties where there output type is set to Class Library, but I can verify mine is set correctly:

[image]

I would like to instead have a TapeRedGreen.exe file that will run the program/application, avoiding having to run the setup/install .exe. How can I do this?

Comment: You already do. You don't need to create an installer. Your users will hate you if you dump 50 files on their machine with no way to remove them though.

Comment: "Compile" instead of "Publish"?

Comment: is the `bin/release` output sufficient? note that this will not be single-file, and you'll need any files adjacent to it

Comment: PS: the screenshot you posted isn't just a setup folder, it's a ClickOnce deployment. That's a very special kind of deployment and doesn't happen by itself. Somehow you explicitly created and published a `ClickOnce` application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just build the application and then look in the output folder (under the ***bin*** folder of your project).

The target folder will have the same name of the configuration selected for the build (debug or release).

The last row of the output console will give you the full path.

A quick tutorial from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-building-an-application?view=vs-2022